# How to maintain the text format (No Formatting) when export to excel using XLSX Angular

Tags: html, excel, angular5, xlsx

I have the simplified working code below:

It is trying to simulate and generate 3 rows of data to HTML using  tag. I have it "reference" using #myTable. The Data is being passed and an excel file is being generated (thankfully).

However, the data is formatted by excel (i think on its own during write).

Can anyone guide me on how to not make XLSX not format and export data to Excel as in  tag?

HTML

```
<table #myTable class="table table-striped table-condensed text-nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let number of ['31.03.2020','10.10.2019','0013268']" class="form-group">
      <td></td>
      <td name="col1">{{ number }}</td>
      <td name="col2">{{ number }}</td>
      <td name="col3">{{ number }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="table-export-message" [tableElement]="myTable"
  class="btn btn-default btn-primary float-right tableexport-string target" style="margin-right:10px">
  <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span>
  Export Excel
</button>
```

Component

```
private exportToTable() {
  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.tableElement);
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

  /* save to file */
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'SheetJS.xlsx');
}
```

The result on EXCEL below. As you can see, only '31.03.2020' is displayed correctly.
However,

1. '10.10.2019' is displayed as "10/10/2019" (Expected : 10.10.2019)
2. '0012345' is displayed as "12345" (Expected: 0012345)

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Update with solution 1:
Good idea but not the correct solution as The excel also have ' (apostrophe).
[image]

Also the table displays the apostrophe.
[image]

Comment: Try this "let number of ['\'31.03.2020','\'10.10.2019','\'0013268']" the \' tell excel that the value is string and not number or date.

Comment: Hi @xShen. kindly refer to updated question.  "Good idea but not the correct solution as The excel also have ' (apostrophe). Also the table displays the apostrophe. Also noticed line 2 in excel is still formatted".

Answer (score 5):

I have found how to add the table without any formatting. After taking more time to understand the (abit confusing) README for Angular XLSX, There is a more parameters which will be accepted and one of it being

```
raw : boolean
```

So the updated code line would be:

```
const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.tableElement,  {raw:true});
```